# I need to replace one statement in all my Java entities using shell script or any other better way?

Tags: java, shell

I need to replace one line of code in all my Java entities with either shell scripts or any other better approach.

Need to replace:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "sequence_name", allocationSize = 1)
```

With:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: What posesses someone to format the words ‘*shell scipt*’ in monospace?!

Comment: @DheerajChouhan Simply adding a question mark to a sentence doesn’t make it a (good) question. Please [edit] the post to contain an _actual_ question. Right now it’s all just a requirement. We can’t tell with what you need help.

Comment: @Biffen actually its not the question, its a simple requirement and i need better approach to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with an text editor like Notepad++, open all java entities and do the change for all open entities.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do this

1) If you want to use shell, you can use [sed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) command for inline editing

2) You can write a java class of your whole where you read all files in a given folder, iterate over them, and access them in edit mode to have a replace based on your logic. To read file individually, you can use `BufferedReader`. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753600/creating-writing-and-editing-same-text-file-in-java)

3) If you have notepad++ installed, you can open notepad++, press `ctrl +f`, go to third tab 'Find in files` and give your details as to what is to be replaced with what and in which directory

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this link can be useful for you if you can use bash

Link:
[How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string-with-awk-or-sed)

```
find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/subdomainA\.example\.com/subdomainB.example.com/g'
```

You'll need remplace with your strings.